# Rounding a float that is an str and used in int

Tags: python

I'm trying to replicated a program I made on a Scratch-like application. My problem here is I'm trying to display the user with different numerical data (subtotal, tax and total cost), but when it shows the total cost it gives repeating or terminating decimals. I'd like it to be rounded to two decimals. I've tried adding the **`round()`** command inside the program but it's difficult because I'm trying to round a variable rather than an actual number. This is my code so far (line 25 and 28 I believe is where I'm suppose to add a **`round()`** or on a new line). I'm very new to Python, I'm using version 3.5.0. I also have searched on here, but the answers were too complex for me. In addition, I got this **`error: typeerror type str doesn't define __round__ method`** when adding the `round()` function in places I assume won't work. Thanks. (ignore after the last `else:` statement)

```
#This program asks for the size of pizza and how many toppings the customer would like and calculates the subtotal, tax and total cost of the pizza.
largePizza = 'large'
extraLargePizza = 'extra large'
print ('Answer the follwing question in all lowercase letters.')
print ('Would you like a large or an extra large pizza?')
sizeOfPizza = input()
if sizeOfPizza == largePizza:
    print('Large pizza. Good choice!')
else:
    print('Extra large pizza. Good choice!')
costOfLargePizza = str(6)
costOfExtraLargePizza = str(10)
oneTopping = 'one'
twoToppings = 'two'
threeToppings = 'three'
fourToppings = 'four'
print ('Answer the following question using words. (one, two, three, four)')
print ('How many toppings would you like on your pizza?')
numberOfToppings = input()
tax = '13%'
if numberOfToppings == oneTopping:
    print('One topping, okay.')
    if sizeOfPizza == largePizza:
        subtotalCostOfLargePizza = str(int(costOfLargePizza) + 1)
        **totalCostOfLargePizza = str(int(subtotalCostOfLargePizza) * 1.13)**
        print('Your subtotal cost is ' + str(subtotalCostOfLargePizza))
        print('Your tax is ' + str(tax))
        **print('Your total cost is ' + str(totalCostOfLargePizza))**
    else:
        print('One topping, okay.')
        subtotalCostOfExtraLargePizza = str(int(costOfExtraLargePizza) + 1)
        totalCostOfExtraLargePizza = str(int(subtotalCostOfExtraLargePizza) * 1.13)
        print('Your subtotal cost is ' + str(subtotalCostOfExtraLargePizza))
        print('Your tax is ' + str(tax))
        print('Your total cost is ' + str(totalCostOfExtraLargePizza))
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with doing `round(my_var, 2)`

Comment: I'm just curious about where I should put it in the code. Like in the math part, or in the print part. Also, like before or after the str. (I'm like really new so I don't know much)

Comment: You're storing all your numbers as strings. That's really a silly thing to do if you need to do mathematical operations on them. Keep them as numbers until you're going to write them out! Or better yet, use sting formatting methods and let Python convert your numbers without any `str` calls at all.

Comment: Oh my God...I have no idea why I was making it so complex. Thanks to the both of you. I know what I should do now.

Comment: If you are using money, you should convert to `decimal.Decimal`